# how to select string bigger than mm/yy if the string formatted as mm/yy in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have a column named `exp_date` and date is as mm/yy. i.e: 07/17. I want to select all rows where exp_date is bigger than 07/17

Kindly be informed exp_date type is varchar(6)

Comment: 7/17 of which year?

Comment: @AdamP 17 is the year. as he explained: mm/yy

Comment: Whoops my bad. Not reading closely enough.

Comment: try this         SELECT * FROM `table_name` where exp_date >07/17

Comment: I tried with > 07/17 before i made the post but it's not working.

Comment: so please show us ur sample data ????

Comment: @MohitKumar It is not a date it is a string, therefore your suggestion  wouldn't work, as your suggestion would be understood as 07 divided by 17 by the database.

Comment: Dates have a day, a month and a year. If you don't have all three of those things, it's not a date. It's a string. If you need to sort in date order, use actual dates.

Comment: @KenWhite  I'm talking about varchar(6)

Comment: Why use a varchar to represent a date? You should really use a type meant for dates. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html

Comment: Yes, I know. But your question title and text ask about selecting *dates*, and I'm explaining that you don't have a date. You're asking about how to arbitrarily order some strings (varchars).

Comment: @AdamP i do understood what you talking about. but since my user privileges is limited so i can't create modify it.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have string format, you need to convert it into date format to compare as such:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    m varchar(5)
);

insert into t values 
('06/17'), 
('07/17'), 
('08/17'), 
('09/17'), 
('10/17');

select * 
from t
where str_to_date(m, '%m/%y') > str_to_date('07/17', '%m/%y');
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c425/2

Comment: You need to be consistent with your data type. That is why it is a bad practice to use different data type then its appropriated one. In order to solve your problem you must convert the data based on the format of your string, if you have different formats you need to change your query accordingly. See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/286f00/5
The best solution is to talk with whoever has enough permission to change the field data type, this workarounds will tend to be worst as the time passes